# Cascading dropdown with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, usability, cascadingdropdown

I have a cascading dropdown with jQuery which is using PHP to retrieve its values. I am trying to nail it so that it works in all situations. Basically it should do the following:

- Populate child when parent is selected
- Parent is sticky so if the page is refreshed child should again auto
  populate based on the parent value in the $_POST array.
- If possible I would also like child to be sticky so that the
  child would also be selected and not just re-populated when the page
  is reloaded.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#parent_id").change(function() {
    $("#child_id").html("<option value=\"\">-- Select One --</option>");
    var p_id = $(this).val();
    if(p_id != 0) {
        $.getJSON('./php/includes/child_web_service.php?p_id=' + p_id,function(data) {   
            $.each(data, function() {
                $("#child_id").append($("<option></option>").val(this['child_id_key']).html(this['child_name']));
            });
        });
    }
});

<?php
if(isset($_POST['parent_id']) && $_POST['parent_id'] != ""){
echo "$(\"#parent_id\").val(" . $_POST['parent_id'] . ").trigger('change');";
}
?>
```

Any suggestions on making this more robust would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to populate child when parent is selected
- Store `$_POST` in a variable to make the parent sticky, and use a [ctype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) to validate it
- Use a [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html) to append child to URL, then bind event to read the value and make child sticky on reload